# Boxes animate to the bottom left when browser shrinks while maintaining a consistent size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a row of 4 boxes animate to the bottom left of the web page when the browser shrinks while maintaining a consistent size relative to the browser's size.  Please observe this example from a website's [homepage](https://support.therapytribe.com/): (scroll down to the "Say Hello To Your New Tribe" section just below the hero image).

In my code, the boxes become skinnier and remain inline without moving to the bottom left before eventually stacking at a browser screen width of < 600px.  I applied a curve bezier CSS animation to the boxes earlier and it did not achieve the effect I was looking for.

I'm looking for that bootstrap quality of "stacking the boxes" with the added effect of gliding them to the bottom left when the browser shrinks.  Of course, when the browser grows to fill the screen, the boxes glide to the upper right and display inline again.  Will somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to achieve [this](https://support.therapytribe.com/) effect?

Thank you.

Criteria:

1) All 4 boxes must begin inline and on the same row. 
2) When the browser shrinks, the boxes must glide to the bottom left. 
3) All boxes must maintain a consistent size relative to the browser's size without spilling its content. 
4) Please follow this [example](https://dev.allyu.org) here.

```css
/* Float four columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #97c3d4;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row allyu-support-groups">
        <div class="column support-group">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
            <h3>Card 5</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
            <h3>Card 6</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
            <h3>Card 7</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
            <h3>Card 8</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet, Right now I implement animate(bottom to upper) on pageload. You can change the event as per your requirement. Let me know if you have any query.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>clientell</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="row allyu-support-groups">
    <div class="column support-group">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
        <h3>Card 5</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
        <h3>Card 6</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
        <h3>Card 7</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://dev.allyu.org/wp-content/themes/thrive-nouveau-child/img/avatar.svg" class="support-group-avatar" />
        <h3>Card 8</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>




<style>
/* Float four columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #97c3d4;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.row.allyu-support-groups .column {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 0;
    width: calc(25% - 2%);
}

.row.allyu-support-groups .column img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
}

.row.allyu-support-groups{position: relative;top:300px;}

</style>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".row.allyu-support-groups").animate({top: "0px"});
 

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm not looking for the boxes to animate when the page loads.  I need them to animate to the bottom left when the browser resizes. Please see an example here: https://support.therapytribe.com/

Comment: Please see snippet again. I change the code as per your requirement.